# How to assign indexes to a function handle?

Tags: matlab, indexing, cell-array, function-handle

I'm trying to approximate the integral of the functions "fun_1" and "fun_2"  over the given region. In the case of one single "f" it seems ok. But I want to use a vector "f" instead of a single value to have a vector of "TL" values. I don't know how to handle this problem. The code is:

```
gamma = 1.4;
R = 286;
T = 273.15;
c_1 = sqrt(gamma*R*T);
c_2 = c_1
h = 0.00163;
rho_s = 2750;
M = 0;
m = rho_s*h;
eta = 0.01;
E = 72e9;
v = 0.30;
D = E*h^3/(12*(1-v^2));
f_c1 = c_1^2/(2*pi)*(m/D)^0.5;
f_c2 = c_2^2/(2*pi)*(m/D)^0.5;
n = 1500;
f = linspace(55,7700,n);
for i=1:numel(f)
    omega(i) = 2*pi*f(i);
    phi_2 = @(phi_1,beta) acos(c_2/c_1.*cos(phi_1).*(1+M.*cos(beta).*cos(phi_1)).^-1);
    tau = @(phi_1,beta) ((0.5*(rho_2*c_2/(rho_1*c_1))^0.5...
        +0.5*(rho_1*c_1/(rho_2*c_2))^0.5*sin(phi_2(phi_1,beta))./(sin(phi_1).*(1.0...
        +M*cos(beta).*cos(phi_1)))+0.5*eta*m*omega(i)*(rho_1*c_1*rho_2*c_2)...
        ^-0.5.*(f(i)/f_c2).^2.*sin(phi_1).*cos(phi_2(phi_1,beta)).^4).^2).^-1;
    fun_1 = @(phi_1,beta) tau(phi_1,beta).*sin(phi_1).*cos(phi_1);
    q_1(i) = integral2(fun_1,12*pi/180,90*pi/180,0,2*pi);
    fun_2 = @(phi_1,beta) sin(phi_1).*cos(phi_1);
    q_2 = integral2(fun_2,12*pi/180,90*pi/180,0,2*pi);
    tau_avg = q_1/q_2;
    TL = -10*log10(tau_avg);
end
```

Answer (score 1):

use a cell array. `TL{i}=-10*log10(tau_avg);`

Comment: @MohammadSd: You didn't ask about turning `tau` into an array, why are you indexing into `tau`? Please edit your question and clarify what you want to do.

Comment: @CrisLuengo Thank you. Do you mean I have to ask " How to convert a function handle to an array?" so what's the answer?

Comment: @AnderBiguri Thank you. But the problem is with "tau" itself. If I use tau{i} there is an error like this: "Unable to perform assignment because brace indexing is not supported for variables of this type."

Comment: @MohammadSd I am confused. `tau` is not indexable. where do you want to index it? Can you show the code that does not work, rather that the one that does work?

Comment: @MohammadSd I don't know. Your question sounds like you have `fun_1` and `fun_2`, but you would like to put those in an array instead, something like `fun{i}`. That is where you need cell arrays. If you want "a vector of TL values", and `TL` is currently a scalar, then what is stopping you from doing `TL(i) = -10*log10(tau_avg);`?

Comment: @CrisLuengo Because the "integral2" function cannot integrate arrays. So even I use TL(i) the answer is just one number that repeats in an array due to the last f(i).

Answer (score 0):

I received this answer from a user in MATLAB Answers that worked for me and solved my problem. So the vectorized version compared to the loop is more efficient.

> ... the `integral2` function cannot integrate arrays, although `integral`
> can.  The way to deal with that problem with respect to a double
> integral is essentially:

```
f = randn(1, 25);
fcn = @(x,y) sin(2*pi*f.*x) .* exp(0.1*f.*y);
int2 = integral(@(y) integral(@(x) fcn(x,y), 0, 1, 'ArrayValued',1), -1, 0, 'ArrayValued',1);
```

> This returns a vector the size of **f**.